# How Can I login Twitch via Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying twitch bot like a stay hydrated bot but Twitch login system have an google captcha and my bot can't login twitch I tried manually login but even i choose pictures correctly google captcha say "it was wrong try again"

Comment: Please re-phrase your question. Right now it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you're going to have trouble making a robot do something you can't, i'm guaranteeing the fact you cannot get past a reCaptcha is most likely user error.

[Twitch Developer Documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/)

You're not going to get past Google Captcha with an automation script as they're designed to stop exactly that. Also it's a really crummy way of creating a view bot, im assuming you actually are trying to do that, because if you were actually trying to make a chatbox, you'd know that twitch have things built in to support things like this, so they don't have to try and get around a reCaptcha.

Comment: No, I don't want make an view bot, I know Twitch have  api for like  this jobs but if i use twitch's api i need "oauth tokken" but i want make chat bot working without oauth tokken it is why i use selenium